# <mvc:annotation-driven/> and binding to collections

Tags: java, spring-mvc

Since including `<mvc:annotation-driven/>` I have experienced a problem when binding the selections of multi-select list box to its corresponding list property on the command bean. Before introducing `<mvc:annotation-driven/>` it worked correctly.

I have a custom collection editor:

```
@InitBinder
public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
   binder.registerCustomEditor(List.class, new CustomCollectionEditor(List.class) {
      protected Object convertElement(Object element) {         
         String fieldName = (String)element;

         for (Field field : fields) {
            if (field.getFieldName().equals(fieldName))
               return field;
         }

         return element;
      }
   });
}
```

which previously would result in the form controller receiving a `List<Field>` representing the list selections. However, since using the `<mvc:annotation-driven/>` what I now get is a `List<List<Field>>`.

Can anyone help shed light on this behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might not be even close but...

If you create your own `AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter` to set a custom `webBindingInitializer` on it you need to have `<mvc:annotation-driven />` *after* your `AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter`, otherwise the one created by `<mvc:annotation-driver />` will be in use and your custom binder won't be in use.

Try moving it if it isn't already last.

Other than that I can only suggest to set a break point inside your binder to see if it is called.

Comment: Thanks! That worked a treat! I had the 'AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter' below the '<mvc:annotation-driver />' top start with, swapped them round and all works great now!

Comment: I'm glad it worked :)
Normally order isn't imported in spring configuration so when it is it kinda bits you.